# rosdep stack dependencies

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use rosdep to install the dependencies to a package on ROS fuerte, and I am getting an error. Perhaps someone could help me out.

Suppose I have a stack `foo` which depends on stack `bar`, with manifest:

```
<stack>
  <description brief="foo"> foo </description>
  <depend stack="bar" />
</stack>
```

Suppose I don't have `ros-fuerte-bar` installed on my system. Will

```
$ rosdep install foo
```

prompt me to install `ros-fuerte-bar`? Or is it just supposed to produce an error and fail?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47519/rosdep-stack-dependencies/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep will not install any stack dependencies, only real system dependencies.

If you do not have your stack `bar` released, you cannot release `foo` because debian package generation requires all stack dependencies to also be available as debian packages. Also, it will add `ros-fuerte-bar` to `ros-fuerte-foo`'s package dependencies so when you install `foo` from debian packages, `bar` will also be installed by `apt-get`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3